# Can i use Soccer/football team names in my web, iphone and android apps?

Tags: android, iphone, copyright, webapp

If i don't use logos, player names, sponsors or any images can i use team names in a for profit app? The reason i mention these is that i have seen countless references to images and badges but not the name in text format only.

Eg print the league table or show a fixtures list or show some user stats in relation to a team name in the app.

I read that a court has ruled in 2012 that fixture lists are not copyright-able as they involve pure scheduling logic and no artistic or innovative value. Also i know that logos, shield, images, player names and images etc are copyright-able.

Do team names fall under fair use if it is purely the team name in a fixture list or in a list or teams?

Comment: IANAL. Why do you think TeamNames are okay to use? They are much like any other IP out there.

Comment: My logic is that Logos, pictures, images have artistic merit and value whereas the word or phrase of a football club can be reproduced under fair use policy - fair use being you dont use any marketing images or logos in association with the club for your benefit, you simply show the text of the club name.

Comment: @Byte56 - i am asking the exact question the question you have highlighted omits to answer - can i use the team name text or not? your duplicate question tells me everything i already know - i cant use images, badges, player names or logos. But can i use 'Manchester united'? If i cant, why dont Manchester United sue me for writing 'Manchester United' here?